# Partial uploads with ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest

Is that even possible? Maybe by using the Content-Range HTTP header?
I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Partial uploads certainly aren't possible using the Content-Range: header.

If you have control of the server you can implement your own way of doing partial uploads over HTTP, eg. using a CGI script that you send a POST to with a field to indicate the range of the file to be uploaded.